# How to learn gzip data byte weight?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gzip

How can I receive gzipped data length in bytes? NSURLConnection automatically decompress gzip data, and I can receive length in bytes only for decompressed data. But I need to know length for compressed data, so what size it go from serevr

Comment: You cannot know the true size of the data in a gzipped archive until you decompress it.

Comment: @Donovan I believe the question was about the size of the gzipped data before decompression.

Comment: @neilco I read the question as 'it tells me the size of the compressed file, but then decompresses it before download', which seems silly, so maybe you're right.

Comment: Can you please clarify this for us @user3095583?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `Content-Length` header of the `NSURLResponse`. This will be the length of the gzipped data. This is available via the `expectedContentLength` property of `NSURLResponse`.

**EDIT**: If it's zero, then the server did not set a `Content-Length` header.

Comment: I see only expectedContentLength, but it return 0 always

Comment: If the server is not setting a `Content-Length` header, then that's the result I would expect to see.